# C++ error: incomplete type used in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, incomplete-type

I have the following header helper.h:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

class Helper{
public:
    static float calculateSpriteSize(float imgSize, float screenSize);
};

#endif
```

This is my helper.cpp:

```
#include "block.h"
#include "helper.h"

float Helper::calculateSpriteSize(float imgSize, float screenSize)
{
    return ((imgSize/screenSize)*100);
}
```

But, for some reason, when I call my function calculateSpriteSize on my running code by doing:

```
#include "header.h"


int main(void){
     float h = Helper::calculateSpriteSize( 168.0f, 170.0f );
)
```

I get the following error:

> error: incomplete type 'Helper' used in nested name specifier

Any help would be appreciated.

Block.h looks as follows:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

class Block{
    private:
         int imgID;
         int life;
         float price;

    public:
         Block();

         void setImgID(int imgID);
         int getImgID();
    };

    #endif
```

And block.cpp looks as follows:

```
#include "block.h"

Block::Block()
{

}

void Block::setImgID(int imgID)
{
     this->imgID = imgID;
}

int Block::getImgID()
{
    return imgID;
}
```

UPDATE: I added Helper to the class definition as suggested by Rakete1111. This did not fix the issue though.

UPDATE 2: Changed forward declaration to include. Added other include that was in my code in case its important.

Comment: I don't think that's the cause, but shouldn't it be `float Helper::calculateSpriteSize(...) { ... }`?

Comment: Oops. You are right. I fixed that. But that didn't solve the issue. Same error persists

Comment: are any files being included in helper.h at all?

Comment: No. No files are included in helper.h.

Comment: the 'nested...' error doesn't make sense if your only class is 'helper' and it doesn't  refer to any other declaration. Could you post the entire source?

Comment: Do you have an *Add.h* header that also uses the preprocessor symbol `ADD_H` for its include guards? Instead of wasting everyone's time, including yours, by playing this guessing game, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will make sure to post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example next time. I'm not a regular here at stackoverflow. One way or another you guys helped me found the solution. Thank you all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type introduced by forward declaration is [incomplete type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type). But member function invoking requires the type to be complete, otherwise how does the compiler know whether the member exists or not, and its signature?

You need to include the header file.

```
#include "helper.h"

int main(void){
     float h = Helper::calculateSpriteSize( 168.0f, 170.0f );
)
```

**EDIT**

You're using the same macro `ADD_H` in both "block.h" and "helper.h". It means for

```
#include "block.h"
#include "helper.h"
```

the second including would fail, the content of `helper.h` won't be included at all.

Change the including guard macro name to be unique, better to make it conform to the name of file name. Such as `HELPER_H` and `BLOCK_H`.